# How to get cursore position in console (C++, Linux)

Tags: c++, console-application

I need to get cursor position in console and pass it to variables `x` and `y`.
I tried this variants:

```
void getCursorPos(int *x, int *y) {
   printf("\033[6n");
   scanf("\033[%d;%dR", y, x);
}
```

```
int get_pos(int *x, int *y) {
    char buf[30]={0};
    int ret, i, pow;
    char ch;
    *y = 0; *x = 0;
    struct termios term, restore;
    tcgetattr(0, &term);
    tcgetattr(0, &restore);
    term.c_lflag &= ~(ICANON|ECHO);
    tcsetattr(0, TCSANOW, &term);
    write(1, "\033[6n", 4);
    for( i = 0, ch = 0; ch != 'R'; i++ ) {
        ret = read(0, &ch, 1);
        if ( !ret ) {
           tcsetattr(0, TCSANOW, &restore);
           //fprintf(stderr, "getpos: error reading response!\n");
           return 1;
        }
        buf[i] = ch;
        //printf("buf[%d]: \t%c \t%d\n", i, ch, ch);
    }
    if (i < 2) {
        tcsetattr(0, TCSANOW, &restore);
        //printf("i < 2\n");
        return(1);
    }
    for( i -= 2, pow = 1; buf[i] != ';'; i--, pow *= 10)
     *x = *x + ( buf[i] - '0' ) * pow;

    for( i-- , pow = 1; buf[i] != '['; i--, pow *= 10)
     *y = *y + ( buf[i] - '0' ) * pow;

    tcsetattr(0, TCSANOW, &restore);
    return 0;
}
```

But `getCursorPos` does not work without `printf` what is not suitable for me and `get_pos` always returns x=1 and y=1.

I test it like that:

```
int main()
{
    int x = 0, y = 0;
    SetCursorPos(0, 4);
    get_pos(&x, &y);
    cout << x << ":" << y << endl;
}
```

I change cursor position with `SetCursorPos`:

```
void SetCursorPos(int XPos, int YPos)
{
 printf("\033[%d;%dH", YPos, XPos);
}
```

Please no **ncurses**

OS: Ubuntu

Comment: "But getCursorPos does not work without printf what is not suitable for me" — why so?

Comment: C++ has no concept of a cursor because many targets supported by C++ don't have consoles, so you have to fall back on another library. Maybe you can get the information from your terminal's API . If not... you've just rejected the most common general purpose solution.

Comment: Warning: `int ret, i, pow;` can end in tears. I've seen C Standard Library functions implemented with macros in the past, so you may see `pow` substituted with a ball of code on some systems. Best to not reuse Library names and avoid the possibility entirely.

Comment: Why no `ncurses`. This is what it is designed for to abstract you away from the details of the terminal.

Comment: @yeputons , cause it will be a problem in the application where it will be used

Comment: If you need to do complicated stuff like locating and moving the cursor around, `printf` just isn't the right tool the vast majority of the time simply because it operates on a stream of text and not a grid of characters. You're trying to use two different output schemes and they're working at cross purposes. Use a console library end-to-end, as in no `printf`, or scale back your ambitions.